# Laravel correct slug product

Tags: php, laravel

I have url: http://example.com/product/123123/slug-this-can-be

I want release function when the user modifies slug, and if slug product not correctly, then automatically change this slug correctly in the address bar.

I have:

```
  public function show($id, $alias) {
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    if($alias != $product->alias)
        request()->get('alias') = $product->alias;

    return view('pages.product', compact('product'));
  }
```

`alias` = slug

Route:

```
Route::get('/product/{id}/{alias}', 'Product\ProductController@show')->name('showproduct');
```

My condition not working.
How can I release this?

Comment: Hi Jadasdas, are there any error messages or warnings that you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your condition  you have to redirect to correct url as below

```
if($alias != $product->alias){
  $url = '/product/'.$id.'/'.$product->alias;
  return redirect($url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `str_slug()` method ? very easy to create a slug with this helper in laravel

```
public function show($id, $alias) {
  $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      if($alias != $product->alias)
        $product->alias = str_slug(request()->get('alias')) ;

    return view('pages.product', compact('product'));
}
```